# How can I ignore Rubocop Layout/MultilineArrayBraceLayout rule for consecutive brackets/braces?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I apologize in advance if this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it by searching or looking through the rubocop documentation.

I'd like the following style to be enforced by Rubocop Layout rules for multiline method calls, arrays and hashes:

```
call(
  a,
  b
)

[
  1,
  2,
]

{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}
```

I've accomplished this with these rules:

```
Layout/FirstArrayElementLineBreak:
  Enabled: true
Layout/FirstHashElementLineBreak:
  Enabled: true
Layout/FirstMethodArgumentLineBreak:
  Enabled: true
Layout/FirstMethodParameterLineBreak:
  Enabled: true
Layout/MultilineArrayBraceLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: new_line
Layout/MultilineHashBraceLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: new_line
Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation:
  EnforcedStyle: indented
Layout/MultilineMethodDefinitionBraceLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: new_line
```

However, I'd also like the following to *not* produce a violation:

```
[{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}]
```

Is there any way to make the latter format acceptable to Rubocop?

Comment: I have (hopefully temporarily) removed the `Layout/MultilineArrayBraceLayout` rule as a workaround, but there is now a gap in the style enforcement, so I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: My 2 cent is; either use Rubocop without turning off any cops or just don't use it at all. If you keep adding new rules, later they do give a huge pain when upgrade/update/refactor etc...

Comment: Sorry, that’s not an option. No cops are being turned off. There are several that are disabled by default that we have turned on, and several that we are using non-default options for, but none that have been disabled. Rubocop is fairly flexible in terms of linting options, and I don’t agree with the all-or-nothing approach you suggest.